# What is no-debug-non-zts-20090626?

Tags: php

In `php.ini` I have:

```
extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php/extensions"
```

However, running `php-config` gives:

```
--extension-dir  [/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626]
```

This directory does not exist, and I could not find any information about it on the Web.

Can anyone shed some light on this strange directory?

Answer (score 15):

It's an extension directory for PHP, named after some factors that influence extension compatibility: thread safety (non-zts), debug (no-debug), and engine version (20090626).

I recommend against changing the path. If it doesn't exist, create it, and put your extensions there. It's also where PECL will install extensions.