# PHP error while sending email

Tags: php, email

I am new to PHP. I am trying to send email through PHP.
The error I got while sending is:

```
[23-Sep-2014 15:31:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/ixed.5.2.lin' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/ixed.5.2.lin: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[23-Sep-2014 15:31:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Directive 'allow_call_time_pass_reference' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I don't know how to solve this. I browsed a lot they said some suggestions.

I am new to PHP and I can not find the solution(s) for this. 
Hope you guys help me to complete my first PHP task successfully...

Thanks in advance...

EDIT : Sorry friends even hello world is not working..  I dont know what to do now whether iwant to install anything... Forgive me for asking very silly questions.. Though am very new am struggling..

Comment: Well by the look of it php tries to load dependand extension and fails. Have a look at this question and try to re-install it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414551/what-is-no-debug-non-zts-20090626

Comment: This could be an issue in your php.ini. Check this out [link]https://processwire.com/talk/topic/1724-directive-allow-call-time-pass-reference-is-no-longer-available-in-php/

Answer (score 1):

Check if /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/ixed.5.2.lin really exists.
(i guess it does not)
After that, you should find it:

```
locate ixed.5.2.lin
```

and put it into the location your php is looking for.
(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/)

If locate does not give any results, you have to install the missing library ...

Remark: to do locate, you will need a console, preferrably with root access.

Edit: Also please check if a simple print('hello'); would work, if not, you should fix your PHP install first.

Comment: May i know where that file located in server, whether its located in error.log file location....

Comment: Ya thanks for ur advice. i will check that and comeback to you

Comment: Thanks Gipsk even hello world is not working i think i have to check php installation

Comment: Which distribution you're using ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the binary exists in extension directory on the server OR the extension directory is correctly defined in php.ini. These are the possibilities which is causing problems. Also try setting permissions to 755 on ixed.5.2* once and see if that makes the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all who spent your time to take part in my issue.

I solved that by contacting my server person..

There is some issue in my curl file, One ; is missed out in that.

Now everything works fine..

Special Thanks for Gipsk Jakab .... His answer narrowed my prob...